# Vue.js how to get current locale in i18n language package

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to get my current locale , because i need to check if the current locale === 'en' then return true or false, how can i do this? Vue.js/i18n/vee-validate

main.js :

```
  import { createApp } from "vue";
  import { createPinia } from "pinia";
  import "./index.css";
  import App from "./App.vue";
  import router from "./router";
  import "@/config/vee-validate/rules";
  import "@/config/vee-validate/messages";

   const app = createApp(App);

   app.use(createPinia());
         app.use(router);

    app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: navigator.language

Comment: Please share more details about the vue version and API used

Comment: No, i dont need this, it checks something another, i need locale value, not navigators

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim , vue is V4, i dont use api..   i use veevalidate-s i18n, and i set locale by setLocale('en'), and i just need to check what is my current locale then

Comment: there's no vue version 4, and I mean by API the composition or the options one

Comment: i use vue3, sorry. and i use options api

Comment: Try out `this.$i18n.locale`

Comment: dont work for me..

Comment: do i need to import some additional things to use this?

Comment: Please enrich your question with needed details like the content of `main.js` file and how do you want to use the locale

Comment: i dont have i18n imported in my files, should i import it? and how?

Comment: Yes you should. This was what I just was typing... Use https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/started.html#javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In option API use :

```
this.$i18n.locale
```

in composition API use the `useI18n` function to get the locale :

```js
const {locale}=useI18n()
```

Comment: i use option api, and this.$i18n.locale dont works, it tells properties of undefined

Comment: In your main file you've not configured the vue i18n plugin

Comment: please follow this https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/#javascript